# Audience Targeting on Navigation Links

Tags: 2010, audience-targeting

I have a SP 2010 Enterprise instance, and I have some navigation links that I want to suppress using audience targeting.

I have a particular SharePoint group with my members, and so I go to Look and Feel -> Navigation under settings, and then I edit my link under "Navigation Editing and Sorting".  When I add my SharePoint group as an audience for that link, it doesn't make a difference, the link still shows in navigation regardless of if a user is in the group or not.

Here's the weird thing, I'm just trying to set this for a good ol' fashioned URL, and it won't work.  However, if I perform the same steps, but have the target link point to a sub-site, or library, the audience permissioning seems to work just fine.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Most of the navigation settings are heavily cached within the site collection object cache. If your cache is large (by default it's 100mb so it can already fill a lot into) you might run into a cache issue.

Try to apply all relevant settings (ordering, hiding, audience targeting) then reset your site collection object cache (from the root of your site collection, you must be a site collection administrator)

If you have access to the relevant box, you can also do an IIS reset to ensure it's not a cache issue.

Finally, make sure that you're using the native navigation provider (in your master page or through custom controls). All PortalSiteMapProvider (GlobalNav, CurrentNav, SiteMap, ...) are handling this by themselves but custom code applied on the top of them might void that if not implemented properly (or not relying on these provider).

A final note, remember that you're just hiding the link, someone knowing the target url will still be able to access it.

Comment: Thanks @Francois, that is a handy tip to know. Unfortunately after following the instructions [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa622758.aspx) I still have the same end result, the link shows for a URL...

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking into it, may be worth confirming the user isn't in an AD group (which may be part of the sharepoint group), or has multiple logins (e.g. multiple domains) which means the user is still somehow part of the group.

If you have confirmed the user is not in the group, you could try creating a new sharepoint group and pointing to that, as there may be something not working correctly (or cached as Francois said) in the previous group.

I have used audience targeting a lot to give users contextual information, without issues.
Usually the only query sometimes is if they are not sure how they are part of the group (e.g. indirectly by AD groups or something).  The "Check Permissions" link is gold.